# How may I configure my Pi to interface between my printer/ scanner on the Ethernet port to be accessible across the wifi network?

Tags: wifi, ethernet

I have a MFP (printer/ scanner) that I have connected to my Pi using the Ethernet port, and would like it to be available across the network using the wifi.
At the moment, I have tried all the "solutions" for the Pi to do this I can find on the internet, and now one seems to work for the printer only.
I think to be able to use the scanner, I need to be able to see the MFP IP address across the network.
Currently the only way it seems to work as a printer is for the MFP and Ethernet port to be on a different sub-net. Then the printer appears to be the Pi, as I think it is using CUPS.
Currently, my tablet & phone cannot connect to the MFP, as I suspect they need to be on the same sub-net.
Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: You should first concentrate on fixing the bizarre network you described in your previous post. When you get it sorted ask a question with networking details.

Comment: `I have tried all the "solutions"` - which ones? wouldn't want to waste your time telling you to do something you've already tried